# Why doesn't creating new Block formatting context on parent element disable margin collapsing?

Tags: html, css, margin

I read on MDN that adding `overflow: hidden` or `float` on a containing element creates a block formatting context. This should stop the margin collapsing of inner child elements. But, it doesn't seem to do that. Here's a working example:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

h1, h2 {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>First</h1>
  <h2> Second </h2>
</div>
```

However, adding `float` on individual `h` elements make their margin collapsing disabled.

Why doesn't creating new Block formatting context on parent element disable margin collapsing?

Comment: it will disable a specific margin collapsing (between chilld and parent) not ALL the margin collapsing

Comment: and since you have border here, you can remove overflow because the border is already disabling child/parent margin. Use outline instead of border and you will see the effect of adding/removing overflow

Comment: @TemaniAfif What does border have to do with block formatting content?

Comment: border is one way among many that disable margin collapsing

Comment: @TemaniAfif Do you have a link to any post for that or a fiddle, MDN doesnt mention this.

Comment: *Two margins are adjoining if and only if:
... 
no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them* https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins